# Could not load file or assembly when use Nunit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have a classlib "CoreComponents" that added a reference "WindowsBase.dll" manually.

[problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR1Hz.png)

In the classlib, I add some method that use some class in "WindowsBase.dll".

then,I new a Nunit prject want to test these method. I have added the project reference ,but when I click the debug and step into the method ,there show error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

According to the description above，I think maybe I need to add the reference to the Nunit,so i did that

[problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93aSK.png)

Unfortunately，there show another error:

> System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
> System.BadImageFormatException : Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

The targetFramework is .Net6, both classlib and NunitPrj, and the "WindowsBase.dll" also copy from .Net6 WinDeskApp.Ref.

With this error, I don't know what to do.
I had google some answers like delete the 'bin' folder, but not work.

Is there a solution here or what I did wrong in my operation.

//------------------------------------------------------------------

I have change the targertframe to "Net6-windows", but the problem still exists.

coreComponent csproj：

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" Version="1.0.1823.32" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase">
      <HintPath>lib\WindowsBase.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

NUnitPrj csproj：

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\CoreComponents\CoreComponents.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Don't manually reference System libraries. Remove the reference to and delete the local copy of WindowsBase.dll.

Comment: thanks, but if I remove the reference, how can I use classes from "WindowBase.dll" that is come from "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" framework. Although there is a same name dll in "Microsoft.NetCore.App", but not exist the class that I need. Should I change the classlib targetFramework to ".Net6-windows"?

Comment: Yes, if you need to use functionality that is only available on Windows, you need to specifiy `net6.0-windows` as target framework. It will then automatically be available.

Comment: Unfortunately, I try to change the targetframe to "Net6-windows" just now, both classlib and NunitPrj, but there are the same both error.  (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: Please add your csproj to the question. Maybe there's something else wrong as well.

Comment: Thanks, already added both csproj, and I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: I really think that removing the reference to windowsbase.dll will fix it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have fix the problem, targetframe change is necessary, additional operation is remove the winbase.dll and add a tag <UseWPF> in classlib csproj, then .net will automatically reference the WinDeskApp.Ref. that contains the winbase.dll. It looks like can't use winbase.dll alone. Anyway, Thanks ♪(･ω･)ﾉ